# In Bootstrap 5 float left is not working with accordion

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I want my images to display side by side inside of an accordion component. When I use `float: left;` or `float: right;` the accordion drops down but then it goes right back up. The content still displays, however the background does not stay put. I learned that bootstrap has its own float for the class class="float-end". I used that one and the whole thing disappears. I tried wrapping it around another div and set the float on the div but it still doesn't work. Then I tried using `text-align: left;` however, everything just get put below the previous element. The only time it works is if I take a second element, and get rid of `float`. It stays but the second element is too far to the right, and I want to make sure it works with just one image there. Lastly, I tried to use this component by itself, just to see if it was something in my project that was messing it up, and by itself, it's still doing the same thing. You can paste this code into an online bootstrap sandbox and see exactly the problem I'm facing. I made sure to include an online picture for the image.

Here's the code. Also, this is all inline CSS, I'm testing things out, excuse my poor management.

```
 <div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="friends" style="margin-top: 55px; box-shadow: 5px 1px 10px #888888;" >
                <div class="accordion-item" >
                    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingOne">
                        <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseOne" style="box-shadow: 5px 1px 10px #888888;" >
                            Friends List
                        </button>
                    </h2>
                    <div id="flush-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample" style="box-shadow: 5px 1px 10px #888888;" >
                        <div class="accordion-body">
                            <div class="friendspictures" style=" margin-left: 5px; position: relative; right: 10px; float: left; ">
                                <img src="https://qph.cf2.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-134e3bf89fff27bf56bdbd04e7dbaedf.webp" alt="" style="border-radius: 100%;  " width="70px" height="70px"  >
                                <p >Josèp</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: What is your goal? Why do you want to use `float`?

Comment: @Cervuscamelopardalis i want to put images side by side going from left to right. And that's what float is used for. Unless you know another why for me to put images side by side

Comment: See my answer below.